# Concatenate 2 Tensorflow dataset for model training

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I have 2 tensorflow datasets of (384,384) images that I want to use as input data and labels data for my model.train()

```
data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory('path1', labels=None, image_size=(384,384), batch_size=1)
labels = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory('path2', labels=None, image_size=(384,384), batch_size=1)
```

But it doesn't let me pass both `x` and `y` as Datasets.

```
model.train(data, labels, epochs=5)
```

> ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using dataset as input.

So what can I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that your first argument (`data`) includes both data and labels (a tuple), and `model.fit()` does not expect to get another argument as `y`, as you have specified `labels`.

Based on this [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory):
If you don't specify `label_mode` argument, it's default is `int`. Then, what this object returns is:

- If `label_mode` is `None`, it yields `float32` tensors of shape `(batch_size, image_size[0], image_size[1], num_channels)`.
- Otherwise, it yields a tuple (images, labels), where images has shape `(batch_size, image_size[0], image_size[1], num_channels)`, and labels if `label_mode` is `int`, the labels are an `int32` tensor of shape `(batch_size,)`.

**Inference:**

Just pass another argument as `label_mode` and set it to `None` like this:

```
data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory('path1', labels=None, label_mode=None, image_size=(384,384), batch_size=1)
labels = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory('path2', labels=None, label_mode=None, image_size=(384,384), batch_size=1)
```